# Using Autolayout to set scaling rules for objects

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode5, autolayout

[image: A screen grab of the Storyboard view layout]

As you can see from the grab, I have all my spacing sorted and am pinning the leading & trailing edges properly; I am stuck on getting my buttons to scale horizontally so the space in-between stays the same. The conflict is all related to the fact that I haven't set a fixed width for the button, but in this case I don't want it fixed.

How can I resolve this autolayout conflict? Does it need some kind of width constraint? That defines a minimum at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select both buttons
- click add constraints menu
- select equal widths
- select buttons one by one and add other constraints till all lines turn to blue like image below.

Hope it helps.

[image: Constraints]